# Doesnt show my session to echo

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 different .php files. At the **first** php file you choose a league to show . The **second** php file shows teams of the league you clicked on the **first**. I have set a session variable but yet it shows a blank page. Why?
Code: 
leagues.php

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($conleague) > 0)
        {
            echo "<table id = 'legaa' width='100%'>"; 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conleague))
            {
                echo"
                    <tr>
                    <th> <a href = 'teams.php'> ".$row['LeagueName']." </a></th><th>  ".$row['LeagueID']." </th>

                    </tr>";
            }
            echo"</table>";
        }

        $_SESSION["LeagueTeams"] = $row['LeagueName'];
        $_SESSION["LeagueNum"] = $row['LeagueID'];
```

teams.php

```
       $leagues = "SELECT team.TeamName, team.TeamID, team.Overall,     team.Budget from teaminfo team WHERE LeagueID = '$_SESSION[LeagueNum]'";

        $conleague = mysqli_query($con,$leagues);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($conleague) > 0)
        {
            echo "<table id = 'legaa' width='100%'>"; 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conleague))
            {
                echo"
                    <tr>
                    <th> <a href = 'showteams.php'> ".$row['TeamName']." </a></th><th>  ".$row['TeamID']." </th> <th> ".$row['Overall']." </th> <th> ".$row['Budget']."</th>

                    </tr>";
            }
            echo"</table>";
        }
```

I have set on both session_start but yet it doesnt print something :/
P.S: My leagues are 4 each league has one id (1-4) shouldn't it print teams that are connecting to each LeagueID ?

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code, use `var_dump();` and look at your HTML source.

Comment: No need to set session to do that. and also you have set session after loop. But when you click on link no session is set.

Comment: Bikash is there a way i could do it without a session? I am new to all these and trying to be more comfortable with all these differencies :)
Thanks Fred.
EDIT: How i could do session inside the link? It shows me errors when i try

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're putting the ID from the league as a string in your query. I don't know what your database design looks like but you could try

```
... WHERE LeagueID = $_SESSION[LeagueNum]";
```

You could also try doing a var_dump() on session in teams.php to check if the variable contains anything at all.

Final note: When are you setting the $_SESSION variable? Looking at it now it doesn't look like you are controller which team you're setting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used a var_dumb and it says string(22) "4 " to  $_SESSION[LeagueNum]"
Anyway i think i am doing it wrong. What i really want is to get result from user. If user clicks on each league to show each teams from each league he clicked. How can i do that? Is there another proper way to implement that?
EDIT: I put session inside loop and it the result of session is 4 (because i have 4 leagues)

Comment: First priority is to get the page showing something, it will be much easier to build the desired result if you have something to test.

Comment: Sorry hit enter too quickly, but since the page is blank means that the if statement if false. That means that your query is not fetching a result. It might be because sessions is currently a string "4". You could try `WHERE LeagueID = intval($_SESSION["LeagueNum"])`. What also might help is vardumping the $conleague query, see if it's a correct query.

Comment: its a correct query because when i does Where LeagueID  = 2 (just to test it) it shows me all teams that are linked to LeagueID 2

Comment: Then i'd say there is something wrong with setting the session. Because when you var_dump() it, you said it is a string(22). The 22 refers to it's length. So somehow the variable is set to a length of 22 characters. Can you try to put the desired ID in a variable using a form or maybe a jQuery/JavaScript script? Use $_POST["LeagueNum"] when posting with a form (try using a form rather than a table maybe, or do some research on how to use those together). Javascript can come in handy too, it offers you some functions to get the value of a desired element and you can assign it to a variable.